# how set language condition with automapper?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I receive the language through endpoint and I want to use the automap to return the same language that I received from endpoint
How can I do something like that knowing I'm using Dependency injection with IMapper

`[HttpGet("Products")] public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int SectionId ,bool IsSection, [FromHeader] string lang){....}`

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    
    public MappingProfile( string lang )
    {
        
          CreateMap<Product, ProductDTO>()
          .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, (lang== "ar") ? src => src.MapFrom(src => src.NameAr) : src => src.MapFrom(src => src.NameEn))
          .ForMember(dest => dest.CountryName, (lang == "ar") ? src => src.MapFrom(src => src.Country.NameAr) : src => src.MapFrom(src => src.Country.NameEn))
          .ForMember(dest => dest.HaveSection, src => src.MapFrom(src => src.Id != 0))
          .ForMember(dest => dest.ByPiece, src => src.MapFrom(src => src.ProductUnit == Units.number))
          .ReverseMap();
        
    }
}
```

i need to do that but with automapper

```
  List<ProductDTO> productDTOs = new();
        if (products !=null)
        {
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                var productDTO = new ProductDTO();
                productDTO.Id = product.Id;
                productDTO.Name = (lang == "ar") ? product.NameAr : product.NameEn;
                productDTO.Price = product.Price;
                productDTO.HasOffer = product.HasOffer;
                productDTO.OfferPrice = product.OfferPrice;
                productDTO.CountryName = (lang == "ar") ? product.Country.NameAr : product.Country.NameEn;

                productDTO.ByPiece = (product.ProductUnit == Units.number) ? true : false;
                productDTOs.Add(productDTO);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I think you should not put domain login inside mappings, but this will become your profile if you want:

```
public MappingProfile( string lang )
    {
        
          CreateMap<Product, ProductDTO>()
          .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, src => src.MapFrom(x => (lang == "ar") ? x.NameAr : x.NameEn))
          .ForMember(dest => dest.HaveSection, src => src.MapFrom(src => src.Id != 0))
          .ForMember(dest => dest.ByPiece, src => src.MapFrom(src => src.ProductUnit == Units.number))
          .ReverseMap();
        
    }
```

Now you need to create a mapper with this profile.

```
IMapper mapper = new MapperConfiguration(x => x.AddProfile(new MappingProfle("ar"))).CreateMapper();
```

Now use this to map your object :)

Comment: Is there a way that I can change the lang in a dynamic way, I mean that I am  send “ar” in one controller  and in other controller i send “en” by Dependency injection with IMapper interface

Comment: yes i understand now, but by this line i need to create new object from mapper every request i get in my API

Comment: Get the language on startup, create a new mapper like I showed and register that, `services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(mapper)`. Now when you request an IMapper you will get this instance always. Finally if my answer solved your problem, please accept it and leave an upvote ;)